Number of solutions of parametric equation $\sin\left(a(\sin x+\cos^2x)\right)=0$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$
I am trying to find the number of solutions $N(a)$ of the following parametric equation:
$$\sin\left(a(\sin x+\cos^2x)\right)=0,$$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and $0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}.$
What I have done:
we can write $\sin x+\cos^2 x =-\sin^2 x +\sin x +1=-[\sin^2 x-\sin x-1]=-\left[\left(\sin x -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}\right]=\frac{5}{4}-\left(\sin x -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$ and since $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]\Rightarrow\sin(x)\in [0,1]$ it follows that $\frac{5}{4}-\left(\sin x -\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\in \left[1,\frac{5}{4}\right]$ thus $$a(\sin x+\cos^2x)\in \left[a,\frac{5}{4}a\right].$$
From the above it follows that the question is how many positive integer multiples of $\pi$ belong to the interval $\left[a,\frac{5}{4}a\right]$ as a function of $a$, and this is where I get stuck, so I would appreciate any hint about how to solve this last step. Thanks.

This answer assumes your work up to the question in your last paragraph is correct, and addresses that question: Given $a>0$, you want to know how many positive integers are in the range $[\tfrac{a}{\pi},\tfrac{5a}{4\pi}]$.
The least integer no smaller than $\tfrac{a}{\pi}$ is $N_a = \lceil \tfrac{a}{\pi} \rceil$, and the greatest integer no larger than $\tfrac{5a}{4\pi}$ is $N_b = \lfloor \tfrac{5a}{4\pi} \rfloor$.

If $\lceil \tfrac{a}{\pi} \rceil > \lfloor \tfrac{5a}{4\pi} \rfloor$ (that is, $N_a > N_b$), then there are no integers in $\left[\tfrac{a}{\pi}, \tfrac{5a}{4\pi}\right]$.

Otherwise $\lceil \tfrac{a}{\pi} \rceil \leq \lfloor \tfrac{5a}{4\pi} \rfloor$ (that is, $N_a\leq N_b$), and the number of integers in $\left[\tfrac{a}{\pi}, \tfrac{5a}{4\pi}\right]$ is
$$\boxed{N_b - N_a + 1 = \lfloor \tfrac{5a}{4\pi} \rfloor - \lceil \tfrac{a}{\pi} \rceil + 1}.$$


The idea here is to find the largest integer interval $[N_a,N_b]$ with $\tfrac{a}{\pi}\leq N_a \leq N_b\leq \tfrac{5a}{4\pi}$

Thanks! One thing: I think the answer should be $2\left(\lfloor\frac{5a}{4\pi}\rfloor-\lceil\frac{a}{\pi}\rfloor +1\right)$ since for $x\in [0,\pi/2]$ we are traversing the interval $\left[a,\frac{5}{4}a\right]$ twice.

I will have to interpret this answer in terms of the original question to be sure about that. I was only answering your secondary question "...how many positive integer multiples of $\pi$ belong to the interval $[a,\frac54a]$ as a function of $a$."

Ah, my bad, I did not read your answer again before posting my comment so I forgot that you were addressing that specific question. Thanks again.
